# send mail form not sending mail

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

I have a form that pops up when the user clicks a link and then sends an email to the address of their choice.  The form looks great, but the email isn't getting sent...

```
<a href='#emailpopup' id='sendMessage'><img src="images/email.jpg"></a>

    <div id="tellfriend" class="contact_form">
      <a class="close" href="#close" >Close</a>
      <form id='tellafriend_form' method="post" action="http://naturesfootprintinc.com/sendmail.php">

        <label for="name">Your Name: </label>
        <input class="std_input" type="text" id="name" name="name" size="40" maxlength="35" value="" />

        <label for="to">Friend's email: </label>
        <input class="std_input" type="text" id="to" name="to" size="40" maxlength="35" />

        <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
        <input class="std_input" type="text" id="subject" name="subject" size="40" value="Check this out!!" />

        <label for="message">Message: </label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" readonly="readonly" rows="18" cols="40">Custom message</textarea>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="form_but" value="Submit"/>
      </form> 
    </div><!-- #tellfriend -->
```

Scripts used:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script> 
$(function() {
    $('#tellfriend').hide();
    $('#sendMessage').click(function(e) {
        $("#tellfriend").fadeToggle('fast');
    });

});
</script>
```

Sendmail.php:

```
<body>
  <div id="thankyou">
    <h1><strong>Thanks for sharing!</strong></h1>
    <p><a href="http://homepage.com">Back to homepage</a></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Yeah, I'm a novice here.  Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: What code are you using to send the mail?

Comment: Is the form actually being submitted?  Is this a client-side or server-side issue?

Comment: your never sending anymail. anywhere. period.

Comment: @blackessej: Which part of `sendmail.php` are you expecting to send a mail?

Comment: The email isn't getting sent because you never send an email.  You need to actually send an email for it to be sent.  sendmail.php just outputs some HTML, it doesn't actually do anything, it needs to send the email.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input.  At the risk of shedding more reputation points: can anyone suggest what I need to implement here to send the email?

Comment: @blackessej: Check out PHP's [`mail()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some server side code to send the mail. Just having a form doesn't do anything for you

So to send it on that click:

```
 $('#sendMessage').click(function(e) {
    var $form = $('#tellafriend_form');
    $.post($form.get(0).action, $form.serialize(), function(data){
          //something on success
    })
    $("#tellfriend").fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: This is what I thought at first, then realized it does not matter. The javascript code was just a red herring. There's no reason the form wouldn't post normally.

Comment: @Wesley, yea i see that. there is no div (or button) with an id of `sendMessage` hmmmm

Comment: @blackessej, well if you just click submit it should submit without any js help

Comment: `<input type="submit" name="submit" class="form_but" value="Submit"/>` This is the submit button. Do I just add the id `sendMessage` to this input?

Comment: for the second time. if its s normal submit, there is no need for javascript

Comment: no, I get it.  I'm sorry, just tried to edit my comment and then reposted it instead, not seeing your responses.  Thanks, @Neal.

Comment: @Neal: His code `$('#sendMessage').click(function(e)` does not do anything to prevent the default form submit so this is not a javascript problem. @blackessej: You need to provide more details, like does `sendmail.php` get called or not. We have no idea what that code even does so there's no way to tell why the email is not sent. Does the form work without javascript? Do you understand: There's no code in this question that would send an email.

Comment: @Wesley, I'm trying to recreate this: http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/creating_a_tell-a-friend_pop-up_form_with_jquery_and_expressionengine/ minus the expressionengine.

Comment: @blackessej That's great but you didn't answer any of my questions. Please add all relevant info to your original question, not hidden in comments.