# Form for sending mail not sending

Tags: php, javascript, email, sendmail

I have a "tell a friend" pop up email form that allows users to share my page with an email address that they enter.  It pops up fine, but I can't get the form to send the email.

html:

```
<div id="tellfriend">
      <a href="#close">Close</a>

      <form id='tellafriend_form' method="post" action="#sendMessage" name="tellafriend_form">

        <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />

        <label for="to">Friend's email:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="to" name="to" /> 

        <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" /> 

        <label for="message">Message:</label> 
        <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

      </form>

</div><!-- #tellfriend -->
```

javascript that handles the "pop up":

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#tellfriend').hide();
    $('#sendMessage').click(function(e) {
        $("#tellfriend").fadeToggle('fast');
    });

});
</script>
```

php that's supposed to send the mail:

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
// This will check to see if the form has been submitted
$senders_name = $_POST['name'];
// The person who is submitting the form
$recipient_friend = $_POST['to'];
// The forms recipient
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
// The subject line
$message = $_POST['message'];
// The message being sent
mail($recipient_friend, "From $senders_name", $subject, $message);

if (isset($_POST['your_email'])) {
echo "<br>Your friend has been contacted <br><br>Thank you $senders_name";
}}
?>
```

Disclaimer: PHP newbie, hoping to learn.  Thanks!

Comment: Is it even calling the PHP file (check access logs)

Comment: Learn how to set headers to send email

Comment: @BugFinder I've tried calling the php file externally and loading it on the page.

Comment: @blackessej, sadly that didnt answer my question. Which was wether your code above is actually calling the PHP (which you would tell from access logs).

Comment: possible duplicate of [send mail form not sending mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969075/send-mail-form-not-sending-mail)

Comment: @Neal yes, it is.  I spent some time trying to teach myself how to use the php `mail()` function, and I'm still struggling.  Here to learn and get help.

Comment: @BugFinder yes, checked the access logs and it was calling the php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your parameters in mail function is not correct. see [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

it should be

```
mail($recipient_friend, $subject, $message);
```

if you want to use headers then do this

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";    
$headers .= 'To: '.$recipient_friend.' <'.$recipient_friend.'>' . "\r\n";    
$headers .= 'From: '.$sender.' <'.$senderEM.'>' . "\r\n";
```

Then call mail like this

```
mail($recipient_friend, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Success.  Thanks so much, @boug.  You just alleviated a huge headache, and I learned a lot in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You have one error in your PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
```

should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

with a lowercase "s".

Indeed the name of you submit button is "submit" but the value is "Submit". 
You could eventually do that:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) &&  $_POST['submit'] == 'Submit') {
```

And your mail parameters are not correct like boug said.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors

1. first:

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['submit']))
   // $_POST is case sensitive
   ```
2. second:

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['your_email']))
   // you dont have an inout named 'your_email'
   ```